# Working on setting order on the CTR highest on top and issues displaying data in DE

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

```
SELECT 
Distinct D.URL AS [Link],a.jobid AS [JobID],F.Emailsubject AS [Email Subject],a.Country as Country,a.consumerlanguage as consumerlanguage,
CAST((SUM([Unique Clicks]) SUM([Sent]) * 100) AS DECIMAL(5,2)) AS CTR,

(
  SELECT COUNT(d.EventDate) 
  FROM _Click d
  WHERE a.JobId = d.JobId 
  GROUP BY d.JobId
) AS [Total Clicks],


(
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN d.EventDate <> '' THEN Subscriberkey END) 
  FROM _Click d
  WHERE a.JobId = d.JobId
  GROUP BY d.JobId
) AS [Unique Clicks],

(
  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN b.EventDate <>'' THEN SubscriberKey END) 
  FROM _sent b
  WHERE a.JobId = b.JobId 
  GROUP BY b.JobId
) AS [Sent]


FROM [Click Activity - Sweden] a
Left JOIN _Sent B  ON A.JobID = B.JobID
left JOIN _Open C ON A.JobID = C.JobID
left JOIN _Click D ON A.JobID = D.JobID
left JOIN _Unsubscribe E ON A.JobID = E.JobID
left JOIN _Job F ON A.JObId = F.Jobid
left JOIN _Bounce g ON A.JobId = g.JobId
GROUP BY a.JobID,F.Emailsubject,ConsumerLanguage,Country,D.URL
```

I'm trying to re-create this set up from marketing cloud but some problems occurred.
I have problem with replicate the "NET CTRs" so the highest value is on the top of the links.
[image: Trying to re-create this]

Another problem that arrived recently is that if a only one email is sent out on a job id and the receiver don't open the email it breaks the CTR reporting on every job id before that occurrence.
[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Thank you!